# How to get the specific item from array on click in javascript table created using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

My code is this

```js
var html = "<table>";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  html += "<tr>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].personName + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].fatherName + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].personPhone + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].personCnic + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].deliveryDate + "</td>";

  html += "<td>" + data[i].submissionDate + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].year + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].session + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].board + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].amount + "</td>";


  html += "</tr>";

}
html += "</table>";
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = html;
```

How can I use an event listeners using this approach?
I have seen many methods but none of that match my scenario.

Comment: are you using react ?

Comment: nope simple javascript

Comment: i don't know how to add event listner

Comment: To what element you want to add event listeners?

Comment: i wnat to get the event listner on the tr of the table

Comment: i upvoted your question to remove that -2 gave you an answer below :) goodluck tell me if it works (comment at the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an onClick which is different for every row, in there you pass as parameter the row index :) than you can handle it on the function.

```
var html = "<table>";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        html+="<tr onclick='myFunction("+i+")'>";
        html+="<td>"+data[i].personName+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+data[i].fatherName+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+data[i].personPhone+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+data[i].personCnic+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+data[i].deliveryDate+"</td>";

        html+="<td>"+data[i].submissionDate+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+data[i].year+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+data[i].session+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+data[i].board+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+data[i].amount+"</td>";


        html+="</tr>";

    }
    html+="</table>";

function myFunction(x) {
  console.log('index' + x + 'was clicked')
  // do the handling here
}
```

**HERE YOU HAVE YOUR DEMO**

```js
   let data = [{ personName: "test1"}, {personName: "test2"}]
   var html = "<table>";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        html+="<tr onclick='myFunction("+i+")'>";
        html+="<td>"+data[i].personName+"</td>";

        html+="</tr>";

    }
    html+="</table>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;
  
  function myFunction(i) {
  console.log('index ' + i + ' was clicked')
  // do the handling here
  console.log(data[i])
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: how would i get the reference to that tr

Comment: it will get it from the  **i** of the loop  , look it carefully not just 20 seconds and reply

Comment: `html+="<tr onclick="myFunction("+i+")">";` use `html+="<tr onclick="myFunction(this, "+i+")">";` and `function myFunction(tr, x) {`

Comment: i think you didn't get my problem

Comment: Sir this is how  you give the parameter to get the specific item, you can do everything with the index  like :     data[x] etc
feel free to upvote

Comment: okay balaj thanks but i am not able to add a function like tis my complier throw me an errror

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: please help me i'll definitely upvote your answer when i ll get the solution

Comment: sorry my bad,  it needed to be 'myFunction("+i+")'       and not "myFunction("+i+")" , i uplaod a new answer with DEMO , feel free to upvote + accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

You can add the event listeners after you adding their html into the DOM.

Like this:

```js
document.getElementById("box").querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(tr => {
  tr.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(tr.textContent);
  });
});
```

And working demo: (I added some dumb data so the demo will work)

```js
const data = new Array(5).fill(0).map((_, idx) => ({
  personName: `personName-${idx}`,
  fatherName: `fatherName-${idx}`,
  personPhone: `personPhone-${idx}`,
  personCnic: `personCnic-${idx}`,
  deliveryDate: `deliveryDate-${idx}`,
  submissionDate: `submissionDate-${idx}`,
  year: `year-${idx}`,
  session: `session-${idx}`,
  board: `board-${idx}`,
  amount: `amount-${idx}`
}));

var html = "<table>";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  html += "<tr>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].personName + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].fatherName + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].personPhone + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].personCnic + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].deliveryDate + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].submissionDate + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].year + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].session + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].board + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + data[i].amount + "</td>";


  html += "</tr>";

}
html += "</table>";
const box = document.getElementById("box");
box.innerHTML = html;
box.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(tr => {
  const _tr = tr;
  tr.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(_tr.textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```